# git diff проверить что изменения из ветки "Dev" не вносят изменения в ветку "Master" в папку prom

Tags: git

Это нужно к примеру в jenkins когда мы сливаем 2 ветки и нужно убедиться что ветка "B" не меняет файлы в ветке "А" в конкретной папке, но сама ветка "А" может что-то менять в этой папке

Comment: Выносите папку в отдельный репозиторий.

Comment: а использовать git status, посмотреть на список файлов и понять, меняет что то или нет?

Comment: все это должно работать без участия человека

Comment: `git diff master...dev -- prom`

Comment: @Наташа ну так пишите на баше/питоне/любимом языке, который поддерживает дженкинс.

Comment: интересует то, как будет выглядеть команда в git которая вернет условно true / false в конкретном кейсе

Comment: у меня есть команда git diff one_branch two_branch, в которой можно указать какие файлы сравниваем, а как понять что если например one_branch редактирует папку "directory" то он должен вернуть что все ок это true, а если two_branch редактирует папку "dirctory" то он должен вернуть ай яй яй так нельзя делать - false

Comment: Вам нужно осознать, что именно означает что "ветка two_branch редактирует папку А". В ветке много коммитов и там безусловно будет коммит (возможно далеко в истории), который менял папку А. То есть вам нужно смотреть не было ли изменений в А начиная с некоторого момента в истории ветки `two_branch`. Скорее всего вы хотите найти место в истории, где `one_branch` и `two_branch` разошлись, т.е. найти ближайший общий коммит Р, который принадлежит и `one_branch` и `two_branch`, в истории и посмотреть изменения в А на отрезке `P..two_branch`.

Comment: Хм, мой комментарий выше невидимый что ли?

Comment: Alexey Ten, спасибо! комментарий хороший, попробую как дойдет время до этого, сама наткнулась в доке нативной, что-то похожее на правду, но надо затестить)